# Ignoring the rest of the line once input has been gotten in C

Tags: c, input, scanf

Given input like:

```
6 2
1 2 3 4 5 6
4 3 3 4 5 6
```

Where first number in 
first line is number of variables in line, second one is number of lines.
 How it is possible to get only first `n/2` values, where `n` is number of values in a line and skip to the next line?

Comment: can you plz elaborate ? question is not clear , what type you want exactly int or char or for all types

Comment: The type im going to need is Int

Comment: Without knowing `n` ahead of time, you cannot read n/2 items *only*, no more than you can tell with certainty my nieces age when I tell you it's half my wife's. You need to know `n`, and since 'n' is the (linelength-1)/2 to account for the ending newline, you need to read the whole line. What you choose to keep as *relevant* data is entirely up to you.

Comment: I specified a problem, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: completly agree with @WhozCraig

Comment: You know `n`. So read (and store) `m=n/2` items; then read (and discard) `n-m` items.

Comment: How to discard n-m items ? Just making (scanf("%d")) in a loop or there is better way ?

Comment: You are so quick to accept an answer, @asnewbie. Give it some time and help will continue to come in :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm surprised no one mentioned `fscanf("%*d")` - that `*` sign tells `fscanf` to read an integer value, but to ignore it (see the documentation [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/)). This lets you do something like:

```
int numbers[MAX_NUMS];
int n = numbers_in_line();
for( i = 0; i < n; i++ )
   if(i<n/2)
      fscanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
   else
      fscanf("%*d");
```

which seems clearer than just reading in the rest of the chars. If you knew `n` ahead of time, you could also just write:

```
scanf("%d %d %d %*d %*d %*d",&numbers[0],&numbers[1],&numbers[2]);
```

You didn't ask about this directly, but if you were reading binary data, there is an additional way to skip the rest of the line. You could read what data you want, then calculate the location of the beginning of the next line (some pointer arithmetic here) and use the [`fseek`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fseek/) function to jump ahead to that location, which could save some I/O time. Unfortunately, you can't do this with ASCII data because the numbers do not take up uniform amounts of space.

Answer (score 4):

If the input length doesn't vary (For example, 6 numbers like your example), you can read your desired input using:

```
scanf("%d %d %d", ...);
```

then, dispose the rest of the input:

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF);
```

If the input length **does** vary, you'll have to read it into a buffer. Then you can iterate over the string to find the number of spaces in it (So n = spaces + 1), then iterate again using `strtok` n/2 times to get the first n/2 numbers.

Comment: It might be worth noting that `...` in your first code snippet doesn't literally mean `...`, but "your variables here".

Answer (score 0):

Previously, do you know how many numbers there are in a line? if your answer is yes, I suggest you try this:

```
int n = numbersInALine(); 
int i = 0;
int *numbers = (int*) malloc( sizeof( int ) * ( n / 2 ) );
for( i = 0; i < n/2; i++ )
    scanf( "%d", &numbers[i] );
```