# C Language - WHILE loops working more that it's supposed to

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, char, getchar

I want to get the user to select a choice. So I declared a variable named ***Choice*** and I want it to input a `char` that can only be `'M'`, `'C'`, `'O'` or `'P'`.

This is my code :

```
char Choice;
printf("Select something to do  :\n'M':Model Parametering\n'C':Calendar creation\n'O':Calendar Output\n'P':Calendar Print\nChoice==>>");
    Choice = getchar();
    while(Choice!='M' && Choice != 'C' && Choice != 'O' && Choice != 'P'){
    printf("\nIncorrect choice, Try again\n");
    printf("Select something to do  :\n'P':Model Parametering\n'C':Calendar creation\n'O':Calendar Output\n'P':Calendar Print\nChoice==>>");
    Choice = getchar();}
```

The thing is when I test it with a wrong value (inputting a character that is NOT in `['M','C','O','P']`, the while loop works more than once.
For example if I input `"TEST"` instead of `'M'`, `'C'`, `'O'` or `'P'`
the while works 5 times not only once like I want!
Why is this happening?

Comment: The `getchar()` function only accepts on character at a time.  If you enter **TEST**, it's going to get called multiple times.

Comment: Hey, you have to indent that code -- it's rough.  The reason it gives you five responses to "TEST" is that "TEST" has 4 characters in it:  T, E, S, T, and the enter character '\n'.  It's doing what it should.  If you want it to throw away the rest of the line, try ignoring the rest of the line of input:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518037/ignoring-the-rest-of-the-line-once-input-has-been-gotten-in-c

Answer (score 1):

After entering `TEST` (4 character worth), you also pressed *Enter*. This is the fifth character (newline, really) passed to your program. Same way, after doing a single character (and *Enter*), the loop runs twice - first for the character itself, then for a newline.

Answer (score 0):

You have given input `TEST` it has 4 character so stdin has 4 character so 4 times `getchar()` can execute. then on next `getchar()` it will again wait for next input from stdin.

Comment: If I input a character that is  NOT in ['M','C','O','P'] the while works 2 times

Answer (score 0):

getchar() considers a character individually from stdin.By providing the input as "TEST", it first reads 'T' , loops again, reads E, loops again, reads S and so on, until it can ask for another character again, which is the 5th loop.

Comment: If I input a character that is  NOT in ['M','C','O','P'] the while works 2 times

Comment: Is there other code  to it ? If you consider what you have given as an entire program, the while works only once and the program ends.

Comment: i.e. 'N' will run the loop once, since 'O' is a valid option, the loop breaks.

Comment: Apologies, since I misunderstood. The reason why the while loop runs twice, is because getchar first considers the invalid character, the first loop occurs, then it considers the enter that you pressed as the next character, the second loop occurs.